# Number alignment and spacing in tables with parentheses, text, decimals, and integers

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I am having a lot of trouble aligning numbers with different format and text within a table environment. After doing a lot of research, I only get as far as the following:

[image]

The rows X to Z and Fstat are not correctly centered (I have tried table-number-alignment=center and it did not work). In addition, each column does not share equal space and stars in column CC are already outside of the table. How should I resolve these issues?

My codes are posted below. Note that they are currently set up so that my estimates are aligned by decimals and parentheses are properly displayed (and these are also what I want).

Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{l *{5}S[table-format=-1.3]}
\midrule\midrule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CC} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} \\
\midrule
X & -0.333^{***} & -0.222^{***} & -0.776^{***} & -0.333^{***} & -0.662^{***} \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.026) & (0.048) & (0.001) \\ 
Y & & -0.004 & & \\ 
  & & (0.008) & & \\ 
Z & 0.111 & 0.122 & 0.123 & 0.122 & 0.133 \\ 

Obs & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$55,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} \\ 
FE & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} \\
Fstat & & 0.225 & 0.221 & 0.222 & 0.220 \\
\midrule\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want the numbers to be aligned at the period?

Comment: I do and after doing research, I decided to use siunitx for that. However, I cannot get them centered (note row X Y Z are not centered as row Obs and FE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use braces around all of your repeated column specifier: `*{5}{S[...]}` not `*{5}S[...]` to apply the options to every column. That leads to an answer that looks very similar to [Mico's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440151):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{parse-numbers = false}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{5}{S[table-format = +1.5]}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CC} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} \\
\midrule
X & -0.333^{***} & -0.222^{***} & -0.776^{***} & -0.333^{***} & -0.662^{***} \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.026) & (0.048) & (0.001) \\ 
Y & & -0.004 & & \\ 
  & & (0.008) & & \\ 
Z & 0.111 & 0.122 & 0.123 & 0.122 & 0.133 \\ 

Obs & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$55,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$56,000$} \\ 
FE & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} \\
Fstat & & 0.225 & 0.221 & 0.222 & 0.220 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(When `parse-numbers = false` is set, `siunitx` uses the same approach as `dcolumn` for alignment.  So the main issue is making sure it knows how many digits to leave space for.)

Comment: +1. :-) It might be a good idea to encase the instances of `,` in the Obs row in curly braces, lest TeX think that the commas are punctuation marks rather than thousands-dividers. And, drop all 18 instances of `\multicolumn{1}{c}` -- they're not needed.

Comment: @Mico I wondered about the `,` too: I'd naturally use `\num` here as we are talking about `siunitx` :) Agree also that the header could be simplified, but that's probably going to distract from the core point.

Comment: Won't the `parse-numbers = false` setting keep `\num` from inserting thousands-separators in the 5-digit numbers, though?

Comment: @Mico Yes if it applies globally, but then one could use the optional argument to `\num`. In the real use case, `parse-numbers = false` might be applied in the optional argument to the `S` column: in that case, it won't be active if `\multicolumn` is used (as that applies before the standard column definition).

Comment: Ah, so there's a potential use case for *not* omitting the `\multicolumn{1}{c}` strings...

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thank you very much!!! Your edits worked. I just have two more questions: 1. What does "@{}" do? It seems that it cuts some spaces around the table.  2. If \sisetup{parse-numbers=false} makes siunitx the same as dcolumn, what is the advantage of siunitx?? I mean without this setup, my parentheses will not be displayed properly.

Comment: How should I insert "," properly other than adding {} around it? I am writing everything in Stata and this becomes really challenging @JosephWright

Answer (score 5):

In your test document, the only use of the `siunitx` package seems to be its `S` column type, to align numbers in columns on their decimal markers. (Otherwise, why issue the instruction `\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}`?) If that's the case, you could simplify the document setup considerably by employing the `dcolumn` package, whose one and only job is -- you guessed it -- helping to align numbers in columns on their decimal markers.

Oh, and please use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` instead of `\midrule\midrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering  %\small  % "\small" doesn't seem necessary
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{5}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\toprule
& \mc{AA}  & \mc{AA}  & \mc{AA}  & \mc{BB}  & \mc{CC} \\
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} \\
\midrule
X & -0.333^{***} & -0.222^{***} & -0.776^{***} & -0.333^{***} & -0.662^{***} \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.026) & (0.048) & (0.001) \\ 
Y & & -0.004  & & \\ 
  & & (0.008) & & \\ 
Z & 0.111 & 0.122 & 0.123 & 0.122 & 0.133 \\ 

Obs & \mc{$55{,}000$} & \mc{$56{,}000$} & \mc{$56{,}000$} & \mc{$56{,}000$} & \mc{$56{,}000$} \\ 
FE & & & \mc{Yes} & \mc{Yes} & \mc{Yes} \\
F-stat & & 0.225 & 0.221 & 0.222 & 0.220 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, especially for your annotation! They worked as well. I have seen people recommend using siunitx instead of dcolumn, but why?    Also, you recommended using toprule and bottomrule instead of double midrule, is there a particular reason? (if I like the double line look).     Lastly, this is probably a very basic question, what is the role of "#1" in the setups? My guess is that it indicates an input??

Comment: @JamesH - If one's objective is solely to align numbers in a column on their decimal markers, I don't think it's correct to claim that `siunitx` package (and its `S` column type) is somehow better than the `dcolumn` package. In fact, I'd say that the setting-up overhead is larger with `siunitx`. About dual lines at the top and bottom of a table: Professional typographers tend to frown on them as they (the dual lines) can look amateurish. Finally, about the `#1` marker: Indeed, it marks where the first (and in this case only) argument of the `\mc` command should be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

A different `siunitx` realization: the numbers in the bottom part need not be aligned at the decimal point.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewDocumentCommand{\snote}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\ensuremath{^{#2}}}
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{#2}$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\sisetup{
  table-align-text-post=false,
  table-space-text-pre={x(},
  table-space-text-post={)x},
  input-symbols={()},
  group-separator={,},
}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{5}{S[table-format = -2.4]}
%  @{\quad}
}
\toprule
& {AA} & {AA} & {AA} & {BB} & {CC} \\
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} \\
\midrule
X & -0.333\snote{***} & -0.222\snote{***} & -0.776\snote{***} & -0.333\snote{***} & -0.662\snote{***} \\ 
  & (0.003) & (0.002) & (0.026) & (0.048) & (0.001) \\ 
Y & & -0.004 & & \\ 
  & & (0.008) & & \\ 
Z & 0.111 & 0.122 & 0.123 & 0.122 & 0.133 \\ 
\midrule
Obs & \num{55000} & \num{56000} & \num{56000} & \num{56000} & \num{56000} \\ 
FE & & & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
Fstat & & \num{0.225} & \num{0.221} & \num{0.222} & \num{0.220} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Use `\snote{...}` for getting zero space, `\snote*{...}` for the natural width.

[image]